# How to run query up to batch separator command in SSMS v19

Tags: sql-server, database, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms-19

I work with SQL Server and Oracle. For Oracle, use SQLDeveloper and to run the query, just place the cursor on the line where the execution is done up to where the "/" or ";" appears. And in SSMS v19, is there any add-in or native option?

I tried to install this add-in [ssms-executor](https://github.com/devvcat/ssms-executor), but it doesn't have compatibility for SSMS v19 yet.

Comment: In an SSMS query window, select the statements/batches you want to execute and press F5.

Comment: Aside... in SQL Server the `;` character is a *statement terminator*. The batch separator is the non-standard T-SQL keyword, `GO`, which is only recognized by SSMS, sqlcmd and a few other tools.